# How to dynamically bind images using Jquery elastic grid plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, elastic-grid

I'm using jquery elastic grid plugin for displaying an images in thumbnail grid with expanding preview. It is working perfectly while binding static images, but i'm getting error like 'tags is undefined' while appending images dynamically.

Can anyone help how to resolve this error ?

sample code:

```
$("#elastic_grid_demo").elastic_grid({
                'showAllText': 'All',
                'filterEffect': 'popup', // moveup, scaleup, fallperspective, fly, flip, helix , popup
                'hoverDirection': true,
                'hoverDelay': 0,
                'hoverInverse': false,
                'expandingSpeed': 500,
                'expandingHeight': 500,
                'items':
                [
                   {
                    'title': 'ABCD',
                    'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
                    'thumbnail': ['/Images/CatalogImage/user_196/148/ThumbImage/myprofile_2014123017329999.png'],
                    'large': ['/Images/CatalogImage/user_196/148/OriginalImage/myprofile_2014123017329822.png'],
                    'button_list':
                    [

                    ],
                    'tags': ['Self Portrait']
                  }
               ]
```